# querying issue on android studio with back4app

Tags: android, sql, android-studio, back4app

I'm using android studio for a dating app project, using back4app for the database. I'm trying to implement the search advance function, as users select the age range, they will only see posts from users who are in the age range.

```
        rangeSeekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar bar, Object minValue, Object maxValue) {
                Number min_value = bar.getSelectedMinValue();
                Number max_value = bar.getSelectedMaxValue();
                int min = (int) min_value;
                int max = (int) max_value;

                setMinAge(min);
                setMaxAge(max);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Min=" + min + "\n" + "Max=" + max, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        });

        btnFilterSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(FilterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("gender", getGender());
                i.putExtra("minAge", getMinAge());
                i.putExtra("maxAge", getMaxAge());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

querying:

```
        ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        ParseQuery<Post> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Post.class);
        query.include(Post.KEY_USER);
        query.setLimit(20);

        if (!(x.equals("everyone"))) {
           query.whereEqualTo("gender", x);//gender filter
           query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("age", minAge);
            query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("age", maxAge);
        }

        query.addDescendingOrder(Post.KEY_CREATED_KEY);

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Post> posts, ParseException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Issue with getting posts", e);
                    return;
                }
                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                for (Post post : posts) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Post: " + post.getDescription() + " , username: " + post.getUser().getUsername());
                }

                for (Post post : posts) {
                }

                allPosts.clear();
                allPosts.addAll(posts);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }
```

whenever I add  `query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("age", minAge); query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("age", maxAge);`the app would not show anyfeed

Comment: Can you pls log what you have in minAge and maxAge vars?  Also, what is the age field type at back4app?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo minAge and maxAge gets value from the range seek bar, default value is minAge=18, maxAge=100. age field on back4app is Number.

Comment: The query is correct and should work. That's why I asked you to log the var values. Maybe there is some bug and the vars do not actually have the values you expect to have.

Comment: how do i log the var values?

Comment: Using Log.i() in the same way you are logging the other data